# How to remove the app which I have uploaded into the playstore

Tags: google-play, android-keystore

I have uploaded an app into the playstore but now I lost it's keystore file.

I am willing to create new app but I want to delete the old app from my account.

Please suggest me a way how to do it.

Thanking you.

Comment: For delete your app from your account you need to unpublish it. Then you can upload it with new keystore file and new package name

Comment: Can I unpublish my app if some one installs it...

Comment: Yes you can unpublish it. But after that user can't get any updates which have already installed app in device because its already unpublished.

Comment: Thanks Piyush, I shall try get back to you...

Comment: Hi piyush I tried unpublishing it but it is asked for a promo video. Is it necessary to give the promo even to unpublish.